# How can I remove the icon animation from the Bootstrap 5 accordion chevron?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I remove the Bootstrap 5 animation (the rotation of the arrow) on the accordion?

[image]

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

I've tried this :

```
.collapsing {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    display: none;
}
```

And this:

```
.accordion-icon-transform {
 rotate(0deg)!important;
}
```

But neither seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply it to the pseudo-element `.accordion-button::after`, that's where it's being added and transitioned.

```css
.accordion-button::after {
  transform: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```